# FAILING: matlab r2016a installation on linux

Tags: software-installation, matlab, license

I am trying to install Matlab R2016a on my machine. Everything went fine, but when I try to start matlab from terminal, I get this error:

```
nikhil@nikhil-ubuntu:/media/nikhil/8AFAB7E7FAB7CE27/linux_soft/MATLAB/R2016a/bin$ ./matlab
License checkout failed.
License Manager Error -8
Make sure the HostID of the license file matches this machine, and that the HostID on the SERVER
line matches the HostID of the license file.

Troubleshoot this issue by visiting: 
http://www.mathworks.com/support/lme/R2016a/8

Diagnostic Information:
Feature: MATLAB 
License path: /home/nikhil/.matlab/R2016a_licenses:/media/nikhil/8AFAB7E7FAB7CE27/linux_soft/MATLAB/R2016a/license
s/license.dat:/media/nikhil/8AFAB7E7FAB7CE27/linux_soft/MATLAB/R2016a/licenses/trial_0_R2016a.lic 
Licensing error: -8,523.
```

i tried googling for the error, but haven't received any useful information. I don't even see a license.dat file created in any of the directories mentioned.

`/media/nikhil/8AFAB7E7FAB7CE27/` is my Windows partition which I have mounted on Linux. I am installing MATLAB on this partition as my linux partition is running short on storage.

Comment: @NickWeinberg I can't understand anything beyond some problem with my licence file in that webpage. We have a shared student licence for MATLAB and it may take some time before they respond.

Comment: Have you tried calling them? Mathworks Technical Support (508) 647-7000 Monday-Friday 08:30-20:00 ET

Comment: @NickWeinberg Doesn't need to contact support. Everything worked fine after I installed it in my /usr/local/ directory.

Answer (score 0):

The error message itself tells you to go to a webpage to troubleshoot:

http://mathworks.com/support/lme/R2016a/8

Please follow the instructions there; if they do not work, you can contact MATLAB Support directly "for free and fast telephone help."

Also, please note that if there exists a `/home/nikhil/.matlab` folder, it will not be visible in your file manager unless you have "Show Hidden Files and Folders" enabled.